# Should there be an "energy-efficiency" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When trying to provide tags for ["How can error correction codes reduce bit error rate, for same amount of energy"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/129742/15426) I noticed that there was no tag for energy efficiency. [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) has the wiki summary of: "The ratio of output power to input power". (This seems strangely specific as output "work" to input power can also be a measure of efficiency, where "work" may not correspond to energy exactly but the accomplishment of the desired task. The referenced question is not about power conversion as such, which seems to be the focus for [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency).)

(Incidentally, [energy-harvesting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-harvesting) does exist.)

Is there some other tag that would be appropriate or should [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency)'s wiki entry be modified to be more inclusive? (There is a distinction between power efficiency and energy efficiency. I also suspect it would be appropriate for the subject to include concerns about energy use which are not *strictly* efficiency-based since battery life is not purely defined by energy used and energy harvesting (and grid electricity use) can make consuming more energy when it is cheap the appropriate strategy. However, energy budgeting might be excessively general as a subject and might even exclude the referenced question which concerns abstract energy efficiency outside of a system context where a budget would be implied.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expand the definition of [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency). In 99% of cases, power efficiency and energy efficiency are used synonymously. In those cases in which a distinction needs to be made between power (energy over time) and total energy, the question itself can specify what is meant.

Tags are primarily a means of finding relevant quesitons, and a single [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) tag would be the best way of meeting this need.

Comment: Could you edit the tag wiki then?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: OK, I've taken a stab at expanding the definition. Let me know if you think it needs further adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that [efficiency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) is enough, I believe that energy efficiency is the right term to address the topic.

If you think about it, it's about how much energy is dissipated in the "system", whatever it is. Power is just a metric to express the amount of energy that is consumed for unit time; in fact, technically you can't consume or dissipate power, but only energy.

And I can't think of a situation in which one excludes the other, except perhaps with heat dissipation.